# Encoding issue in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, encoding, character-encoding, jsp-tags

I have a problem about `character encoding` in `jsp pages`. Even if i added `charset params` to my page, i still have this problem.  when I statically add Turkish chars to my `jsp page` it is ok, but the text added to the page dynamically by java has charset problem. And i am using `webSphere 6` as app server of my app. This is how i added tags,

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-9" %>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1254">
```

For example the code below read related strings from language txt, and try to print it in jsp. all turkish chars encoded wrong , so that is why they appears wrong.

```
<h2><%=Messages.message("metin1")%>
```

Comment: Can you also post the code which dynamically adds the text. Complete code snippet is required to provide an answer.

Comment: I have just added some code by editing the question.

Comment: Why do you use different charsets for `page` directive (ISO-8859-9) and for `META` tag (windows-1254)?

Comment: yes you are wright it seems to me strange as well. but it was default value while creating jsp file. Furthermore I almost tried all possibilities about these charset values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ensure that your .jsp file is really written with the expected encoding
2. In the servlet that dispatch to the jsp use `request.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-9");`
3. Try to put a tag with a purely ISO-8859-9 character inside.

Comment: YMomb, thanks for your answer. I guess my problem is about the encoding of file. when i check the properties of jsp page in eclipse i can see it is UTF-8. However, after I build the prj by ant, file encoding type of jsp page in wepshere turn to ANSI. still the problem continue

Comment: Are you using Maven for your packaging? In that case, you can configure the encoding of the resources in the maven-resource-plugin.

Comment: no i dont use maven. Even i tried to set encoding charset in web xml for all pages, it did not work again. we have levels of app servers. the problem is in dev mode. same code works well in alfa and prod servers, but it has charset problem in dev

Answer (score 0):

Save the jsp file with utf encoding. Also use

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

in servlet.

Comment: You probably mean request.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-9");